# Where should I put my mirror?

Tags: code-golf, string, palindrome

This is a mirror: `|`. I just found out that you can stick a mirror in the middle of a string if the string can be mirrored on itself! For example, the string `abccba`. If you cut it in half the two halves are mirror images of each other:

```
abc  <-->  cba
```

So, we can stick a mirror in the middle of the string, and our new string is `abc|cba`. Sometimes, only part of the string can be mirrored on itself. For example, the string "mirror". The two r's are mirrored, but the rest of the string isn't. That's OK, we'll just remove the parts of the string that don't mirror each other, and we get the following string:

```
r|r
```

Some strings could be mirrored in multiple places. For example, "Hello World, xyzzyx". I like having a lot of text reflected in my mirror, so you need to find the best place to put my mirror. In this case, you should output the longer mirrored string and just like our last example, remove everything else. This string becomes:

```
xyz|zyx
```

Some strings *look* like they can be mirrored, but actually can not. If a string cannot be mirrored anywhere, you should output nothing.

## The challenge:

Given a string containing only printable-ascii, find the best place to put my mirror. In other words,

> Find the largest even-length palindromic substring, then output it with a pipe character '|' in the middle of it.

The input will be 1-50 characters long.

You can assume that the input will not contain mirrors `|` or newlines. Beyond that, all printable-ascii characters are fair game. If the longest mirrored substring is tied between two substrings, you can choose which one to output. For example, for the string "abba ollo", you must output "ab|ba" or "ol|lo", but it doesn't matter which one you output. Strings are case-sensitive, e.g. "ABba" should *not* output "AB|ba", it should output the empty string.

## Sample IO:

```
"Hello World"     --> "l|l"
"Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf"     --> Either "m|m" or "z|z"
"abcba"           --> ""
"Hulluh"          --> "ul|lu"
"abcdefggfedcba"  --> "abcdefg|gfedcba"
"abcdefggfabc"    --> "fg|gf"
"AbbA"            --> "Ab|bA"
"This input is a lot like the last one, but with more characters that don't change the output. AbbA" --> "Ab|bA"
```

As usual, this is code-golf, so standard loopholes apply, and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Is there a limit on the length of the input?

Comment: @Mego As long as your algorithm theoretically works on any input, I don't care how long it takes/how much memory it takes.

Comment: I asked because vanilla regex engines are only capable of matching palindromes of length up to a specified, finite value (as opposed to arbitrarily-long palindromes), and the possibility of a regex-based solution would depend on whether or not there is an upper bound on the length of the input.

Comment: @Mego Ah, that makes sense. Let's say the input can be up to 50 characters long. How does that sound?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Pyth - <s>19</s> <s>17</s> <s>15</s> 13 bytes

*Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for saving me two bytes.*

<s>ARRGH the special case for no answer.</s> Solved that!

```
e_I#jL\|cL2.:
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e_I%23jL%5C%7CcL2.%3A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Hello+World%22+++++%0A%22Programming+Puzzles+and+Code-Golf%22+++++%0A%22abcba%22+++++++++++%0A%22Hulluh%22++++++++++%0A%22abcdefggfedcba%22++%0A%22abcdefggfabc%22++++%0A%22AbbA%22++++++++++++%0A%22This+input+is+a+lot+like+the+last+one%2C+but+with+more+characters+that+don%27t+change+the+output.+AbbA%22+&debug=0).

```
e                Last element in list, this works out to longest one
  _I             Invariance under reverse, this detect palindrome
   #             Filter
   jL            Map join
    \|           By "|"
    cL2          Map chop in two pieces
     .:Q)        Substrings. Implicit Q). ) makes it do all substrings.
```

Comment: Nooooo! Ninja'd to the pyth answer ;_;

Comment: Explanation please? :3

Comment: @Downgoat he took all substrings and chop into two, join each pair with |, filter by symmetry, append that to [k] and get the last element (which is the longest)

Comment: @Downgoat done.

Comment: `:Q)` = Bignose

Comment: I don't think you need the `+k`, as the error message goes to stderr, and then the program prints nothing. [This](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4781/31625) and [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9427/31625) are relevant meta posts.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman oh, did not know this.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 14 bytes

Code:

```
Œévy2ä'|ý©ÂQi®
```

Explanation:

```
Œ                # Get all substrings of the input
 é               # Sort by length (shortest first)
  vy             # For each element...
    2ä           # Split into two pieces
      '|ý        # Join by "|"
         ©       # Copy this into the register
          Â      # Bifurcate, pushing a and reversed a
           Q     # Check if it's a palindrome
            i®   # If so, push that string again
                 # Implicit, the top element is outputted
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xZLDqXZ5MsOkJ3zDvcKpw4JRacKu&input=YWJjZGVmZ2dmZWRjYmE).

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>102</s> 97 bytes

```python
def f(s):h=len(s)/2;r=s[:h]+'|'+s[h:];return s and max(r*(r==r[::-1]),f(s[1:]),f(s[:-1]),key=len)
```

Rather slow and inefficient... Verify the smaller test cases on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/NckMlB).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>100</s> 99 bytes

```js
s=>eval('for(O=i=0;s[i++];O=O[j+j]?O:o)for(o="|",j=0;(S=s[i-1-j])&&S==s[i+j++];o=S+o+S);O[1]?O:""')
```

**or**

```js
s=>eval('for(O="",i=0;s[i++];O=O[j+j]||j<2?O:o)for(o="|",j=0;(S=s[i-1-j])&&S==s[i+j++];o=S+o+S);O')
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the `eval` for?

Comment: @gcampbell `eval` to avoid `return `

Comment: Can't you use the comma operator to avoid return?

Comment: @SpeedyNinja nope. `for` is not an expression, so it would normally require braces and a `return`

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 133 bytes

```lua
s=...for i=#s,1,-1 do for j=1,#s-i do m=j+i/2-i%2/2t=s:sub(j,m).."|"..s:sub(m+1,i+j)if t==t.reverse(t)then print(t)return end end end
```

[Verify all testcases on Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/OmmYrR).

Comment: Use `t==t:reverse()` to save a byte :)

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 66 bytes

Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding.

```
M!&`(.)+(?<-1>\1)+(?(1)¶)
O$#`.+
$.&
A-2`
^(.)+?(?=(?<-1>.)+$)
$&|
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApNISZgKC4pKyg_PC0xPlwxKSsoPygxKcK2KQpPJCNgLisKJC4mCkEtMmAKXiguKSs_KD89KD88LTE-LikrJCkKJCZ8&input=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQKUHJvZ3JhbW1pbmcgUHV6emxlcyBhbmQgQ29kZS1Hb2xmCmFiY2JhCkh1bGx1aAphYmNkZWZnZ2ZlZGNiYQphYmNkZWZnZ2ZhYmMKQWJiQQpUaGlzIGlucHV0IGlzIGEgbG90IGxpa2UgdGhlIGxhc3Qgb25lLCBidXQgd2l0aCBtb3JlIGNoYXJhY3RlcnMgdGhhdCBkb24ndCBjaGFuZ2UgdGhlIG91dHB1dC4gQWJiQQ) (The first line enables testing of several linefeed-separated test cases at once.)

Hmmm, much longer than I would like...

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 91

```js
s=>[...s].map((d,i)=>{for(a='|',j=0;d=s[i-j],d&&d==s[i-~j];r=r[j+++j]?r:a)a=d+a+d},r='')&&r
```

*Less golfed*

```js
f=s=>
  [...s].map(
    (d,i) => {
    for(a='|', j=0; d=s[i-j], d&&d==s[i-~j]; r = r[j++ +j]? r : a)
      a = d+a+d
    }, r=''
  ) && r
```

**Test**

```js
F=
s=>[...s].map((d,i)=>{for(a='|',j=0;d=s[i-j],d&&d==s[i-~j];r=r[j+++j]?r:a)a=d+a+d},r='')&&r

;[["Hello World", "l|l"]
,["Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf", "m|m"]
,["abcba", ""]
,["Hulluh", "ul|lu"]
,["abcdefggfedcba", "abcdefg|gfedcba"]
,["abcdefggfabc", "fg|gf"]
,["AbbA", "Ab|bA"]
,["This input is a lot like the last one, but with more characters that don't change the output. AbbA", "Ab|bA"]]
.forEach(t=>{
  var i=t[0],k=t[1],r=F(i)
  console.log(k==r?'OK ':'KO ',i+' -> '+r,k!=r?'(check '+k+')':'')
})
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 5, <s>105</s> <s>100</s> 98 + 1 = <s>106</s> <s>101</s> 99 bytes

```
/(?=((.)(?1)?\2)(?{[push@_,$1})(?!))/;($_)=sort{length$b<=>length$a}@_;substr($_,length>>1,0)='|'if$_
```

I just wanted to give recursive regexes a go. Needs the `-p` option. Edit: Saved (crossed out 4) 7 bytes thanks to @msh210. (The missing byte is due to a saving that was superseded by @msh210's latest saving.)

Comment: I haven't tested any of these, but probably this can be abbreviated various ways, including: (1) `@_=(@_,$1)` can be `push@_,$1`. (2) Omit the newlines and the final `;`. (3) I suspect there's a shorter sort condition you can use (if nothing else then at least --- perhaps --- substitute `-` for `<=>`)

Comment: @msh210 Thanks for the first two points but I already tried `-` and it didn't work (probably needs parens for precedence which defeats the saving).

Comment: Try `y...c>>1` or `y...c/2` instead of `length>>1`. (Untested.)

Comment: @msh210 I obviously should have read the tips for golfing in Perl first...

Comment: I'm guessing your last pair of parens can go, also.

Comment: And test (1) whether you really need the `if$_` at the end (maybe it works even for empty `$_`). I suspect you *do*,  but it's worth checking. Also (2) whether this works when the palindromic part is `00`: the `if$_` should fail there and you'll wind up with no pipe. I think.

Comment: @msh210 You need the `if$_` otherwise it outputs a `|` when there's nothing to mirror. There's no problem with `00` though, it's truthy.

Comment: @msh210 I get an error if I try to remove any more parens.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, 91 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,p='':s and max((''<p<=s<p+'\x7f')*(p[::-1]+'|'+p),f(s[1:]),f(s[1:],s[0]+p),key=len)
```

Replace `\x7f` with the actual character DEL, which is ASCII 127 (credit to Dennis).

This follows a similar strategy to [Dennis's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84402/20260) of using `max` and recursively branching to find the longest palindrome interval. But, instead, it finds the left half, checking that the corresponding mirrored right half comes right after it with a [self-made startswith](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51783/20260).

The function guesses whether the first character is in the mirrored left half. If not, it just drops it and recurses on the remainder. If it is, it's added to to the stack `p` of reversed characters. If the string ever starts with the stack, the mirror string is generated and considered as a possible longest mirror. To avoid `|` as an output, only non-empty stacks are considered.

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL <s>227</s> 223 bytes

I hardcoded the length to max 99 bytes, this saved bytes but made it slower. It still have a decent performance though.

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @t varchar(99)='AbccbA'

,@z char(99)='',@a INT=0,@ INT=0WHILE @a<LEN(@t)SELECT
@z=IIF(LEN(x)>LEN(@z)/2and @t LIKE'%'+x+REVERSE(x)+'%'COLLATE
Thai_bin,x+'|'+REVERSE(x),@z),@=IIF(@=50,1,@+1),@a+=IIF(@=1,1,0)FROM(SELECT
SUBSTRING(@t,@a,@)x)x PRINT @z
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @t varchar(99)='AbccbA'

,@z char(99)='',
@a INT=0,
@ INT=0
WHILE @a<LEN(@t)
  SELECT
    @z=IIF(LEN(x)>LEN(@z)/2and @t LIKE'%'+x+REVERSE(x)+'%'COLLATE Thai_bin,x+'|'
       +REVERSE(x),@z),
    @=IIF(@=99,1,@+1),
    @a+=IIF(@=1,1,0)
  FROM
    (SELECT SUBSTRING(@t,@a,@)x)x

PRINT @z
```

**[Fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/507690)**

Comment: You can shave off 2 byte if you limit to 99 as the last example is only 99 chars long

Comment: @VisualBean thankyou, changed the script to only allow 99 characters, also changed the collation from Thai_CS_AS to thai_bin

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>126</s> 111 bytes

```
(!)=drop
f s|n<-length s=last$"":[a++'|':b|k<-[1..n],t<-map(!s)[1..n-k],let[a,b]=take k<$>[t,k!t],a==reverse b]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
►S=↔ΘmoJ'|½Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY09TgQxDIWvYk2zzcINKFYUrKgWsRIFonAmniRaJ0b5EdKKBgpOgBBnQaLhABxiLhIMI1G95@89276VQ4/z81Of3z6uz@aX1@/3KJerx6/Pq9777bAlZoEbyWyH9bDL4jLGGJKDXTsemQpgsnAulk4uhCftoBkNqm4bc/MLsDQ5N5Fdkn@gRseNMRuVvQ8FQrpvFdQgsFTgcCConoCxVJBEazCaP4TqIUomGD1mHCvlojWsYCWt6i9NblmUVvXiKfw9ufsB)

-1 from Leo.

Comment: [Save 1 byte](https://tio.run/##PY09TgQxDIWvYk2zzcINKFYUrKgWsRIFonAmniRaJ0b5EdKKBgpOgBBnQaLhABxiLhIMI1G95@89276VQ4/z81Of3z6uz@aX1@/3KJerx6/Pq9777bAlZoEbyWyH9bDL4jLGGJKDXTsemQpgsnAulk4uhCftoBkNqm4bc/MLsDQ5N5Fdkn@gRseNMRuVvQ8FQrpvFdQgsFTgcCConoCxVJBEazCaP4TqIUomGD1mHCvlojWsYCWt6i9NblmUVvXiKfw9ufsB "Husk – Try It Online"). I feel like more should be possible but couldn't find anything else

Comment: Huh. I thought `Q` didn't order by length and it'd fail for some testcase. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 149 bytes

```py
R,L,s=range,len,input()
t=max([s[i:j/2+i/2]for i in R(L(s))for j in R(L(s)+1)if s[i:j]==s[i:j][::-1]and(j-i)%2<1],key=L)
print t+'|'*(L(t)>0)+t[::-1]
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/jxoIbM)

This program finds the first half of the largest palindromic substring of even length, and prints that string, followed by a `|`, followed by that string reversed. If there is no suitable string, `t` will be the empty string, and `'|'*(L(t)>0)` will evaluate to the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>294</s> <s>283</s> 232 bytes

```java
s->{int l=s.length(),i=0,j,z,y=0;String a,b="";for(;i<l;i++)for(j=0;j<=l-i;)if((a=s.substring(i,i+j++)).equals(new StringBuffer(a).reverse()+"")&(z=a.length())%2<1&z>y){y=z;b=a;}return y>0?b.substring(0,y/=2)+"|"+b.substring(y):"";}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jVJNb9swDL33V3AG1kmw42U9znGGbof1sqLABuww9EDbtC1XljJJTmFn@e0Z0xpFLkUKSAA/Hh/JB3a4xYXdkOmqh0Op0Xv4gcrsLgCUCeRqLAlujy7Az@CUaaAUs@FlxvE9f34@YFAl3IKBHA5@sd5xPejcp5pME1ohE5Uvky6ZkjFfZjMFJkUeRVltncjUSmcqjuXR6RjSrXK9UJlUtRDIPH4o/FOVUImKO0bKlP4OqL0w9DhP93Woa3ICZepoS86TkHEUyUsx5fgyiXx/tfp0Oa1HuRvzKStyzPaOwuAMjOvll@Kk1TIZP@ZXzPEvik/jo/zMc@8P2fP2m6HQvP0swtaqCnqWcVbqzz2gnDUcfaA@tUNIN5wK2giTliK6Ia1tAr@t09W7SD4p@zr6ztnGYd8fJbwbpkmTBzQVfLMVLb5bXZ9lwKIs8CzqZtB6aN9CVlHdNDVVb2F9gbNxFnxdFNdnQb9a5fleN0MANhC05dNTDwShJeCjDmANJVBw/lGFFnrrCMoWHZZ8455hGKCy5kM4Rk3zXMhtmDGFkxH2F/vDfw)

```java
s->{                               // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  int l=s.length(),                //  Length of the input-String
      i=0,j,                       //  Index-integers
      z,y=0;                       //  Temp-integers
  String a,b="";                   //  Temp-Strings
  for(;i<l;i++)                    //  Loop (1) from 0 to `l` (exclusive)
    for(j=0;j<=l-i;                //   Inner loop (2) from 0 to `l-i` (inclusive)
      if((a=s.substring(i,i+j++))  //    Set the current substring to `a`
          .equals(new StringBuffer(a).reverse()+"")
                                   //    If `a` is a palindrome
         &(z=a.length())%2<1       //    And the length of `a` is even
         &z>y){                    //    And the length of `a` is larger than `y`
        y=z;                       //     Change `y` to `z`
        b=a;}                      //     Change `b` to `a`
                                   //   End of inner loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                                   //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return y>0?                      //  If the result-length is not 0:
    b.substring(0,y/=2)+"|"+b.substring(y)
                                   //   Return the result
   :                               //  Else:
    "";                            //   Return an empty String
}                                  // End of method
```